# Finding an intersection point in the rectangle

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

[image: fig 1]

- ABCD is a rectangle on the Cartesian plane with its center at (0, 0)
- AB=a, BC=b
- the rectangle sides are at 45 degree angle with the plane axes
- How do I find OE ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dashed axis (which is the first bisector) has the equation $y=x$. Then the line AD, which is parallel to the former, goes through the point $\dfrac1{\sqrt2}(-a,a)$, giving the implicit equation

$$y-\frac a{\sqrt2}=x+\frac a{\sqrt2},$$ and we intersect with $x=0$.

> $$OE=\sqrt2a.$$

Comment: I don't quite get how you get "goes through the point 1/sqrt(2) * (−,)"

Comment: Oh sorry now I get it. Thanks a lot.